# Except requests in grafana loki

Tags: nginx, grafana-loki

I started using grafana loki for nginx logging. I can’t display the top of certain queries in any way. An example request is: topk(10, sum by (request_uri) (count_over_time({$label_name=~"$label_value", job=~"$job", instance=~"$instance"} !~ `\.ico|\ .svg|\.css|\.png|\.txt|\.js|\.xml` | json | status = 200 and request_uri != "/" | **error**="" [15m]))). How can I get the output of /api/v1/widgets/* only?

Comment: Please, clarify what you have executed and what was the result you got.

Comment: I pasted the command in the question in explorer, the output was the top 10 queries in the last 15 minutes

Comment: Does request_uri =~ "/api/v1/widgets/.*" solve the problema?

Comment: No,it doesn't work